# Does Deadpool ever fly in comics?

Tags: marvel, deadpool, powers

A friend was telling me that he's seen comics where Deadpool had the ability to fly. Has this ever happened in comics? He said that it was through powers, not through tech.

### Has Deadpool ever been able to fly in the comics?

Answer (score 7):

I remember one storyline (may have been a single issue) where Loki seperated Thor from his hammer and made it appear that Deadpool took possesion of it (though it was actually a fake) which granted him Thor like powers.

[image: Image as requested'ith]

Comment: But Thor doesn't fly per-se, he generally uses his Mjolnir to pseudo-fly.

Comment: Answer would be better if it included a picture. SFF loves pictures.

Comment: Answer would be better if it included a free-hand circles. SE loves free-hand circles.